# R select row of data frame interactively

Tags: r, dataframe, interactive

I have a data frame, say:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=runif(10))
```

I'd like to be able to display the data frame to the user and have them select (click) a row, and **retrieve that row**.

Something a bit like `edit(df)`, except that what I want is much simpler in that I don't need editing functions --- I just need to listen for a click event on one of the rows and get the index for that row (I don't even need the particular cell!)

Does anyone know how I can do this? I'd prefer to do it with base R or `grid` (for the sake of not adding in lots of packages) -- maybe I can somehow draw the data frame on a grid graphics with a y scale defined from 1 to `nrow(df)` and use the `grid.locator()` function?

It'd be nice to avoid bringing in gui packages, but if I do, it should be cross-platform (linux/windows). `gwidgets` is quite nice (although they don't seem to have the click event nicely integrated with their `gdf` widget).

cheers.

Comment: If using gWidgets, try gtable, not gdf, as there mouse clicks also trigger editing. The svalue method for gtable with index=TRUE will return the index of the selected row. Otherwise, you could do this with a graphic device, but without scrollbars you will have to limit the size of the data frame you are displaying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well, here's a quick way, no extra packages, but you may have to fiddle with formatting if you want the table to be nicely aligned, rounded, etc:

```
    df <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=runif(10))
    df[menu(apply(df,1,paste,collapse="  "),graphics=TRUE),]
```

The device widens itself if necessary and scrollbars automatically appear when necessary.

Comment: What he asked for was just: `menu(apply(df,1,paste,collapse="  "),graphics=TRUE)`

Comment: oops I thought he wanted the row and not the row index

Comment: And on reading it again, I think your answer is just as plausible.

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I want. I only recently learned about `menu` and forgot about the graphical option. Thanks! (I only asked for the row index so I could use it to get the row - so either or is fine). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest a combination of a blank plot filled with `addtable2plot` and then use `locator` to pick a point and calculate the row with a combination the y-specification and the  `cellheight <- max(strheight(c(column.names, row.names, as.vector(unlist(table)))`,...  but effort in that direction seems silly since @timrifle seems to have hit the nail on the head.