# Specify monospace font in `menu`

Tags: r, fixed-width, monospace

Language: R. Question: **Can I specify fixed width font for the `menu(..,graphics=T)` function?**

#### Explanation:

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176125/r-select-row-of-data-frame-interactively) on how to have a user select a row of a data frame interactively:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(9,10),b=c('hello','bananas'))
df.text <- apply( df, 1, paste, collapse=" | " )
menu(df.text,graphics=T)
```

[image]

I'd like the `|` to line up. They don't at the moment; fair enough, I haven't padded out the columns to the same width. So I use `format` to get every column to the same width (later I'll write code to automagically determine the width per column, but let's ignore that for now):

```
df.padded <- apply(df,2,format,width=8)
df.padded.text <- apply( df.padded, 1, paste, collapse=" | ")
menu( df.padded.text,graphics=T )
```

[image]

See how it's still wonky? Yet, if I look at `df.padded`, I get:

```
> df.padded
     a            b           
[1,] " 9        " "hello     "
[2,] "10        " "bananas   "
```

So each cell is definitely padded out to the same length.

The reason for this is probably because the default font for this (on my system anyway, Linux) is not fixed width.

So my question is:
**Can I specify fixed width font for the `menu(..,graphics=T)` function?**

## Update

@RichieCotton noticed that if you look at `menu` with `graphics=T` it calls `select.list`, which in turn calls `tcltk::tk_select.list`.

So it looks like I'll have to modify `tcltk` options for this. From @jverzani:

```
library(tcltk)
tcl("option", "add", "*Listbox.font", "courier 10")
menu(df.padded.text,graphics=T)
```

[image]

Given that `menu(...,graphics=T)` calls `tcltk::tk_select.list` when `graphics` is TRUE, my guess is that this is a viable option, as any distro that would be capable of displaying the graphical `menu` in the first place would also have `tcltk` on it, since it needs to call `tk_select.list`.

(As an aside, I can't find anything in the documentation that would give me the hint to try `tcl('option','add',...)`, let alone that the option was called `*Listbox.font`!)

**Another update** -- had a closer look at the `select.list` and `menu` code, and it turns out on Windows (or if `.Platform$GUI=='AQUA'` -- is that Mac?), the `tcltk::tk_select.list` isn't called at all, and it's just some internal code instead. So modifying '*Listbox.font' won't affect this.

I guess I'll just:

- if tcltk is there, load it, set the *Listbox.font to courier, and use `tcltk::tk_select.list` explicitly
- if it isn't there, try `menu(...,graphics=T)` to at least get a graphical interface (which won't be monospace, but is better than nothing)
- if that fails too, then just fallback to `menu(...,graphics=F)`, which will definitely work.

Thanks all.

Comment: There's no obvious option.  `menu` calls `select.list`, which disappears into external code.  You might have more luck hacking `tcltk::tk_select.list`.

Comment: @RichieCotton hmm, I thought that might be the case :(. I'll look into `tcltk`. Do you know if it is standard in all R distros? I'd just like to minimise the number of external packages users have to install (as I have quite a number already). Cheers.

Comment: `tcltk` is standard on Windows but not Linux (unsure about OSX).  You can test for support with `capabilities("tcltk")`.

Comment: My cheap solution appears to have only displaced the problem :-( . For what it's worth, I'm on Ubuntu with R version 2.13.1 and capabilities("tcltk") yields TRUE

Comment: You can hack this through the option command. Something like `library(tcltk); tcl("option", "add", "*Listbox.font", "times 16 bold ")` will do it.

Comment: Thanks all - I guess I'll use `tcl('option',...)` (I'm on Fedora, R 2.14, and `capabilitites('tcltk')` is also TRUE for me, although I remember explicitly installing a whole bunch of gui packages). I had just hoped there was something in `options` I could manipulate without loading a gui library.

Comment: @RichieCotton:  Where did you get the 'not on Linux' from? Couldn't be further from the truth.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Ok, bad language on my part. ‘menu‘ starts checking capabilities for Linux so there probably are some  distros where tcltk isn't supported. Agreed that it should be there on most of them.

Comment: @jverzani I know this is resurrecting things a bit, but if you'd like to post your comment as an answer I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to padding:

```
na.pad <- function(x,len){
    x[1:len]
}

makePaddedDataFrame <- function(l,...){
    maxlen <- max(sapply(l,length))
    data.frame(lapply(l,na.pad,len=maxlen),...)
}

x = c(rep("one",2))
y = c(rep("two",10))
z = c(rep("three",5))

makePaddedDataFrame(list(x=x,y=y,z=z))
```

The `na.pad()` function exploits the fact that R will automatically pad a vector with NAs if you try to index non-existent elements.

`makePaddedDataFrame()` just finds the longest one and pads the rest up to a matching length.

Comment: This makes a data frame with `max(length(x), length(y), length(z))` rows and `NA` for those row, columns where there are no values, but I'm not sure how it solves my problem of displaying in `menu(vectorOfDataFrame, graphics=T)` such that the font is either fixed width or appears so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't want to use View(df)  (get the rowid, put the contents into temp. data frame and display it with the View command)

Edit: well, just use `sprintf` command

Create a function f to extract the strings from the data frame object

```
f <- function(x,sep1) {
 sep1=format(sep1,width=8)
 xa<-gsub(" ","",as.character(x[1]))
 a1 <- nchar(xa)
 xa=format(xa,width=8)
 xb=gsub(" ","",as.character(x[2]))
 b1 <- nchar(xb)
 xb=format(xb,width=8)
 format1=paste("%-",10-a1,"s%s%-",20-b1,"s",sep="")
 concat=sprintf(format1,xa,sep1,xb)
 concat
 }
```

`df <- data.frame(a=c(9,10),b=c('hello','bananas'))`

`df.text <- apply( df, 1, f,sep1="|")`

`menu(df.text,graphics=T)`

Of course the limits used in sprintf 10, 20 are maximum length for the number of characters in the data-frame column (a,b). You can change it to reflect it according to your data.

Comment: Besides the fact that that wasn't my question (I specifically wanted to have monospace in `menu`): Note that the `menu` and `View` functions are fundamentally different in that the `menu` function is for **selecting** item(s) (so I can say "choose a row" and have the index/item returned), whereas the `View` function is for **viewing** only.

Comment: Have you considered using `sprintf` command? -- see my modified edit above

Comment: This does not work when `df$a` goes into three digits (try `data.frame(a=c(9,10,100),b=c('hello','bananas','x'))`), but you've certainly made me curious - with the `df` in your answer I notice that  `nchar(df.text)` is `c(32,29)` - how did you know that these strings of unequal length would align the '|' when it's the 10th character of the first string but only the 9th character of the second?

Comment: I've done a bit more playing around, and I think you may have just got lucky with the example `df` I put in my question - when columns contain more general text, e.g. `data.frame(a=c('green','eggs','wwww'),b=c('and','ham','lll'))` this runs into trouble with non-monospace fonts because (for example) a `w` is very fat compared to a `l`. I think sprintf won't work in general for aligning data.frame columns *unless* the font is also monospace, hence my original question.

Comment: It aligns, try a bigger value like 12 instead of 10 on  `sprintf` in  `format1=paste("%-",10-a1,"s%s%-",20-b1,"s",sep="")`. (12-a1) The values NEEDS to be changed depending upon your string length of characters. I chose a random number 10, but you can determine the size once you determine the maximum length of that column from the dataframe.

Comment: I know. I hacked up a version that uses 2*maxWidth as the value which works great when it's just numbers in the first column and letters in the second, but the moment you put letters in the non-last column of varying width (e.g. fat 'w' vs little 'l'), you run into trouble unless the font is monospace or you can perfectly compensate for the extra width with spaces, which is font-specific.